# Movesense iOS guide

Tags: movesense

I'm trying to use a Movesense device in an iOS app, but I'm not sure how to begin. There is an Android developer guide on the Movesense website, but no equivalent for iOS. Can anybody point me towards some literature on how to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [movesense-mobile-lib (link to iOS readme)](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/src/master/IOS/Movesense/readme.txt) repository for how to connect and query of information from the sensor on iOS.

And in the [movesense-device-lib (link to YAML api definition location)](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/) for what is possible to request from the phone side.

I hope this what you where looking for.